# Is this set of equations solvable?

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve a set of equations.  I ran it for several days but it's still running.  Is this solvable?

```
Solve[{
-(a - X)/c + (X - Y)/e + S^2*X*(X - Y)/(r + f) - 0.5*S^2*f*(X - Y)^2/(r + f)^2 == 0,

(Y - b)/d - (X - Y)/e - S^2*Y*(X - Y)/(r + f) - 0.5*S^2*f*(X - Y)^2/(r + f)^2 == 0,

S^2*e/r - Z == 0,

lambda1 (1/c + 1/e + (S^2 X)/(r + f) - (f S^2 (X - Y))/(r + f)^2 + (S^2 (X - Y))/(r + f)) + (2 
f S^2 (X - Y))/(r + f)^2 + lambda2 (-(1/e) - (f S^2 (X - Y))/(r + f)^2 - (S^2 Y)/(r + f)) == 
0, 

lambda1 (-(1/e) - (S^2 X)/(r + f) + (f S^2 (X - Y))/(r + f)^2) - (2 f S^2 (X - Y))/(r + f)^2 + 
lambda2 (1/d + 1/e + (f S^2 (X - Y))/(r + f)^2 - (S^2 (X - Y))/(r + f) + (S^2 Y)/(r + f)) == 
0, 

lambda1 (-((S^2 X (X - Y))/(r + f)^2) + (f S^2 (X - Y)^2)/(r + f)^3 - (S^2 (X - Y)^2)/(2 (r + 
f)^2)) - (2 f S^2 (X - Y)^2)/(r + f)^3 + (S^2 (X - Y)^2)/(r + f)^2 + lambda2 ((f S^2 (X - 
Y)^2)/(r + f)^3 - (S^2 (X - Y)^2)/(2 (r + f)^2) + (S^2 (X - Y) Y)/(r + f)^2) == 0,

(lambda3 S^2)/r - (lambda1 (X - Y))/e^2 + (lambda2 (X - Y))/e^2 == 0,

(2 lambda3 e S)/r + lambda1 ((2 S X (X - Y))/(r + f) - (f S (X - Y)^2)/(r + f)^2) + (2 f S (X 
- Y)^2)/(r + f)^2 +lambda2 (-((f S (X - Y)^2)/(r + f)^2) - (2 S (X - Y) Y)/(r + f)) == 0}, 

{X, Y, f, e, S, lambda1 , lambda2, lambda3}]
```

Comment: I'm not an expert certainly but I do see that there are a lot of variables (14) with no Domain or constraints so it seems to me more a miracle if this would work. Anyway the proper format is also not used. Solve needs not a list of equations. it needs Solve[eq1&&eq2&&eq3,vars,Domain]. Also eg the first equations shows that f should not equal -r (divide by zero) so that could be a constraints etc

Comment: @Lou I agree with the sentiment of your comment, but note that `Solve` can actually take a list of equations, and it is equivalent to the same equations connected with `And` as you showed. See the second bullet point in the Details and Options of the documentation for Solve: "`Solve[{expr1, expr2, …}, vars]` is equivalent to `Solve[expr1 && expr2 && …, vars]`".

Comment: Why not to use `NSolve` for this problem? There are 8*59 complex roots for a given set of parameters could be found in numerical simulation.

Comment: Hi Alex: I can use NSolve and it works if I give numerical values to the parameters, but I want to study the general features of the solution, so I want to see if I can find an analytic solution.  Thanks.

Comment: @HLi What kind of features do you want to study with 59 complex roots for every variable?

Comment: Hi Alex: If I use NSolve, there is only 1 real solution to the problem.  I want to study how f and e change as a function of the parameters a,b,c,d,Z.  You say there are 8*59 roots to this problem.  I see there 8 variables.  Where does the 59 come from? Thanks.